# Amazon RDS MySQL - Increase maximum indexes to greater than 64

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to increase the maximum number of indexes on a Mysql database running on Amazon RDS.

By default MySQL allows a maximum number of indexes of 64. This limit can be increased by setting the 'with-max-indexes' parameter when compiling MySQL (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,53666,262189#msg-262189).

I want to adjust this same parameter but on a MySQL database running on Amazon RDS. I have setup a new RDS Parameter Group which I can apply to the database, but I can not see any parameter on the RDS web console that would allow me to increase the number of indexes.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Matthew

Comment: what is the reason to setup more than 3-5 indexes per table?

Comment: I currently have data distributed across multiple tables with 3-5 indexes per table as you suggest. I need to be able to perform complex queries with where clauses across multiple fields on each table. These queries work but as I'm scaling up the data to several million records in some tables the performance is getting too slow. So I am creating a master index table which will contain one field for each of the attributes that I query against. The index is updated periodically with the source data. Using a single index table for searches is improving performance massively for me.

Comment: MySQL introduced JSON support and possibility of indexing those fields. With that in mind many will use it as a search engine for their existing document object data.
The limit of 64 indexes sounds backwards. The next limit though is the number of columns which is 4096.
Lack or RDS flexibility is another issue.